# In XSLT, how to access an attribute in a variable which contains a tree fragment with only one node

Tags: xslt, attributes, xslt-1.0, docbook

I work with DocBook XSLT and want to get the id attribute of an anchor. In DocBook the anchor is produced by the following XSLT template:

```
<xsl:template name="anchor">
  <xsl:param name="node" select="."/>
  <xsl:param name="conditional" select="1"/>

  <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="$generate.id.attributes != 0">
      <!-- No named anchors output when this param is set -->
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:when test="$conditional = 0 or $node/@id or $node/@xml:id">
      <a>
        <xsl:attribute name="id">
          <xsl:call-template name="object.id">
            <xsl:with-param name="object" select="$node"/>
          </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:attribute>
      </a>
    </xsl:when>
  </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

I call the template from another template and store the result in a variable:

```
<xsl:variable name="anchorOutput">
      <xsl:call-template name="anchor">
        <xsl:with-param name="conditional" select="0"/>
      </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:variable>
```

With

```
<xsl:copy-of select="exsl:node-set($anchorOutput)"/>
```

I can output the anchor as expected:

```
<a id="d0e1292"></a>
```

However, I also want to extract the value of the "id" attribute in order to create another element.
As far as I understand the topic, the variable anchorOutput contains a tree fragment. So, I tried all variants of:

```
<xsl:value-of select="exsl:node-set($anchorOutput)[1]/@id"/>
```

But even when I try:

```
<xsl:value-of select="count(exsl:node-set($anchorOutput)[1]/@*)"/>
```

I get 0 as a result. So, why it is not possible to get the id with this approach and how can I get it?

Answer (score 0):

The right path would be `exsl:node-set($anchorOutput)/a/@id`, I think. Or, if the `a` element is in the XHTML namespace, you need to declare a prefix for that namespace and use it, e.g. `<xsl:value-of select="exsl:node-set($anchorOutput)/xhtml:a/@id" xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"/>`.

Comment: Is the `a` element in any namespace?

Comment: I don't know. I also tried things like local-name(exsl:node-set($anchorOutput)[1]) or namespace-uri on the variable and got no result.

Comment: The path I suggested seems right with the information given so far, it works at https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/bEJbVrV with a minimal but complete sample. Maybe try to post some minimal but complete sample that allows us to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Does `exsl:node-set($anchorOutput)/*/@id` show the id attribute value? That would indeed suggest the `a` element is in a namespace (is the output format perhaps XHTML?).

Comment: That does it. Yes, I think it should be XHMTL. So, how do I have to address the element?